# Get all a href links using SimpleHTMLDom library & change these on the 'fly'

Tags: php, html, parsing

I'd like to get to all the a href links within the html string and convert all of the links as follows:

```
<a href='www.google.com'>Google</a>
```

Would change to look like this...

```
<a href='www.mysite.com/link.php?URL=www.google.com'>Google</a>
```

Can anyone suggest how I do this?

```
<?php
```

require_once('simple_html_dom.php');

```
// load the class
$html = new simple_html_dom();

// load the entire string containing everything user entered here

$string = "<html><body><base href='http://www.site.biz/clients/g/'><a href='www.google.co.uk'>Google</a><a href='http://www.yahoo.co.uk'>Yahoo</a></body></html>";
$return = $html->load($string);

$links = $html->find('a');

foreach ($links as $link) 
{
    var_dump($link);
}
```

?>

Comment: For reference, i'd highly recommend dumping simple_html_dom altogether.  It actually manages to make PHP segfault here, and eats up 5x as much memory and runs at 1/5 the speed of PHP's built in DOM stuff.  (That's not exaggeration, either.  I timed it running through some test suites i have.  Real world time, not benchmarks.  :P )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried something like

```
$links = $html->find('a');

foreach ($links as $link) 
{
    if(isset($link->href))
    {
        $link->href = 'www.mysite.com/link.php?URL=' . $link->href;
    }
}

$newHTML = $html->save();

// $newHTML now contains the modified HTML
```